# How do I install Debian and bring back a ZFS pool containing /var, /usr and /home?

Tags: debian, zfs

I am administering a server that runs CentOS 7. I want to install Debian 10 on it. I am concerned about the filesystem structure and potential data loss as par of the system is currently on a zfs pool, and I have close to zero experience with it.

The system has a total of 12 physical storage units.

- 2 SSDs (`sda`,`sdb`) are set up in a (currently degraded) software RAID 1 with mount point `/`.
- 8 large HHDs (`sde`-`sdl`) are forming a `raidz2` ZFS pool, with four file systems with mount points `/home`, `/opt`, `/usr` and `/var`.
- 2 SSDs (`sdc`,`sdd`) have three partitions each. The first of both are used as swap. The second partitions of both form a ZFS mirror log device. The third partitions of both act as ZFS cache.

I want to save all the data in the home and var filesystems. I have a plan on how to start, but I'm not sure about how to finish. I have three questions regarding this process.

My idea is to install **all** the system in the RAID formed by sda and sdb. During the Debian installation, I will select both discs (now `sda` and `sdb`) to be used as physical volume for RAID, and select RAID1 as type. Then, install all the system in the same RAID filesystem, except selecting `sdc1` and `sdd1` for swap, and leaving `sdc2`, `sdc3`, `sdd3`, `sdd3` and `sde`-`sdd` untouched.

After the installation is complete this way:

- **Q1**: would there be any problem to boot from a RAID 1 filesystem?

  It was not the case before, but the Debian installation guide says:

  > Make sure that the system can be booted with the partitioning scheme you are planning. In general it will be necessary to create a separate file system for `/boot` when using RAID for the root (`/`) file system. Most boot loaders do support mirrored (not striped!) RAID1, so using for example RAID5 for `/` and RAID1 for `/boot` can be an option.

After the installation is complete, I want to import the pool. The mount points are configured to be `/home`, `/opt`, `/usr` and `/var`.

- **Q2**: How do I proceed to mount the filesystems in the pool when the mount points are already taken by the newly installed system?

An alternative could be to run a live CD/USB and import the pool after renaming the newly created `/home`, `/opt`, `/usr` and `/var`. Then I could move the new `/usr` into the pool filesystem (and the same with `/var`) and, so that all I want in the new system is in the pool file systems. Now,

- **Q3**: how can I set the pool to be imported and mounted automatically for the next boot without the live CD/USB?

Thanks. I hope the question is not too all over the place (since it's three questions indeed). Let me know if there's something I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start I would suggest you run through similar steps in an alternative environment.  I have a [mostly automated vagrant setup](https://github.com/ixydo/vagrant-zfs-on-linux) that stands up a debian instance with zfsonlinux and a few disks.  It's slightly outdated, but without modification it should quickly give you an environment to work with.  Feel free to update it to the latest Debian if you feel the need and raise a PR.

To answer your individual questions:

1. There's no issues booting from RAID1 when using grub.  Grub understands RAID1 just fine and will auto-detect it.  The [dest/50setup-boot script](https://github.com/ixydo/vagrant-zfs-on-linux/blob/master/bootstrap/dest/50setup_boot) in my repo demonstrates specific commands that make this work reliably.
2. I wouldn't recommend re-mounting `/usr` and `/var` from the old system as that is likely to break things.  ZFSonLinux will automatically mount filesystems when the pool is imported, so you'd need to add a couple of steps to disable this before first booting your system.  That would look something like this:

   ```
   zfs set canmount=off tank/usr
   zfs set canmount=off tank/var
   ```

   Alternatively you could change the mount point so you still have it for reference:

   ```
   zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/old-usr tank/usr
   zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/old-usr tank/var
   ```

   If you did want to replace the ZFS `/usr` mount with the new system you could do that as you suggest, but you must make sure that ZFS is enabled at boot via initramfs.  The vagrant example does provide root (`/`) on ZFS, so you should have all the examples you need.

   Regarding `/home`, it shouldn't break things to have this mounted on top of the newly created home system, but it may not work as you expect initially since the system users and the old filesystem won't be in agreement (assuming you're not using an external user management system such as LDAP).  You have a couple of choices here:

   1. Retain the old system `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups` files as reference, then when you boot into the new system you'll need to do some manual reconcilation.
   2. Change the mount point of the old `/home` in a similar way to the `/usr` or `/var` mounts, then do your reconciliation manually afterwards.

   The `/opt` path shouldn't introduce any issues as that is not used by a vanilla Debian system, so that can be left to auto-mount as before.
3. The live CD approach is almost a given for such a re-installation.  For example in the `bootstrap/` folder of my repo the `host/` folder refers to the live environment, while `dest/` refers to the newly installed system.

   In order for the filesystems to be mounted in the new system you'll just need to make sure zfsonlinux is installed and working on the new system.  This is normally handled automatically for you when the `zfs-initramfs` package is installed.  You can double check the `zfs` module is available in the `/boot/initrd.img*` using a command such as:

   ```
   gunzip /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64 | grep 'usr/lib/libzfs.so'
   ```

Overall gaining some experience in a mock environment first will greatly improve your chances of doing this successfully in the live environment.

Comment: Thank you so much JinnKo. I will definitely practise this stuff on the virtual environment you sent

Comment: I have a basic question about ZFS. When you run a command like zfs set canmount=off tank/usr, does that write information somewhere in the configuration of the running system, or it writes it on the ZFS pool disks, so that it would be understood by any system that imports the pool? Applied to this, if I ran that command from the live cd, and later boot on the system (which still has not zfs installed, as it doesn't come with the Debian installer), would it have effect after I install zfs and reboot?

Comment: The properties are native to the zpool/zfs.  [Aaron Toponce's ZFS Administration Guide](https://pthree.org/2013/01/02/zfs-administration-part-xvi-getting-and-setting-properties/) is an excellent reference for all this.